# Python dictionary rounding off

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to Python. I have declared a dictionary in the following form where I require x and y to take values ranging from -20 to 20:

```
pbounds = {'x': (-20,20), 'y':(-20,20)}
```

how do i change this declaration such that x and y take values such that they are limited to 2 decimal places?

Comment: `-20` and `20` are integers, and literal integers at that, so they're already limited to 0 decimal places, so you don't have to change anything.

Comment: I do not understand your question. What exactly are you trying to accomplish

Comment: `pbounds` is just a dictionary where `'x'` and `'y'` are mapped to the tuple `(-20, 20)`. The values of `'x'` or `'y'` could be changed to anything.